# Calculating a definite integral when $1/0$ arises twice and seems to cancel out.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

We have
\begin{align*} I=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\sin x}dx \\
=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}dx \\
=&[\tan x]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx
\end{align*}

And by letting $u=\cos x \Rightarrow du =-\sin x dx$

We get \begin{align*} I=&[\tan x]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} +\left[ \frac{1}{u}\right]^{1}_{0}  \\
=&\frac{1}{0}+1-\frac{1}{0} \\ =&1\end{align*}

Is the last step right? Can you just cancel these out like that or should you do it another way? Because the answer here is in fact $1$. This might be more of an algebra question and that's why I tagged it as such. I've never come across this before.

Comment: The first "infinity" comes from the tan , so I do not think that this solution is valid.

Comment: I think you're getting the correct answer in the end because the part of the integral of $1/u$ that causes a problem is balanced by the part of the integral of $\tan x$ that causes a problem. But since you have not actually **proved** that this is so, all we can say is you've made two mistakes that cancel out by luck. A better approach would be to look for a solution that does not use undefined integrals.

Comment: You can use the antiderivate shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%281%2F%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29)

Comment: Define $F(t)= \int_0^t \dfrac{1}{1+ \sin x}~dx$.  You want $\underset{t \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}{\lim} F(t)$.  Taking the integral without going all the way to $\frac {\pi}{2}$ allows you to avoid dividing by $0$ and makes rigorous the "balancing" that @DavidK describes.

Comment: So is it impossible to get a correct result using $ I=[\tan x]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}+[\frac{1}{u}]^{1}_{0}$ ? I've never seen this kind of a dead-end when integrating but I guess it makes sense. Maybe using limits this could work? Edit: Just saw @Robert's comment. Clears this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LHS equals $1,$ but neither integrand on the RHS is bound on the integration interval and neither improper converges:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}\,\mathrm dx \ne
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\cos^{2}x}\:\mathrm dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}\:\mathrm dx $$

1. As the given integrand is a rational function of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and its interval of integration doesn't contain any odd multiple of $\pi,$ the Weierstrass substitution $$u=\tan\frac x2$$ works, giving $$\int_0^1\frac1{u^2+2u+1}\,\mathrm du,$$ which equals $1.$
2. Alternatively we can take limits, as suggested in Robert's comment:

   \begin{align}&\int_{0}^a\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}\,\mathrm dx = \cdots=\big[\tan x\big]_0^{a}-\left[ \frac{1}{u}\right]^{\cos a}_{1}=\frac{\sin a-1}{\cos a}+1,\\
   &\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}\,\mathrm dx\\
   ={}&\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}2}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}\,\mathrm dx\\
   ={}&\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}2}\left(\frac{\sin a-1}{\cos a}+1\right)\\
   ={}&1,\end{align} by L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Is there a book/other source you know that contains these types of substitutions and maybe other similar less mainstream integrating methods? Preferably with the motivation behind them. I think I remember this particular substitution being described as "the world's sneakiest substitution" by Spivak and this integral in its indefinite for was there but I remember being disappointed at the lack of motivation behind them other that: it just works.

Comment: @Eric The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) does a decent job of motivating the tangent substitution (see the "Derivation" subsection)

Comment: Wikipedia has a great list of sources on this integral which does leave and has been good most of the times I've paid it a visit. I'm looking for a more concentrated source for elementary function integration.

Answer (score 0):

In enforcing $u=\cos(x)\iff x=\cos^{-1}(u)$, we have $dx=-\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ and the integral transforms to

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{1-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt{1-u^2}}{u^2\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du = \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{u^2\sqrt{1-u^2}} - \frac1{u^2}\right) \, du$$

followed by another [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) of $u=-\frac{2v}{1+v^2}\iff v=\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}-1}u$ (to avoid invoking another trigonometric substitution) and $du=-\frac{2(1-v^2)}{(1+v^2)^2} \, dv$,

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac1{u^2 \sqrt{1-u^2}} - \frac1{u^2}\right) \, du = \int_{-1}^0 dv = 1$$

Note how the integral is not distributed over the difference to avoid the issue with the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$.